# Does a person’s soul see through the navel when the person passes away (Ben Ish Hai)

Tags: sources-mekorot, parshanut-torah-comment, midrash, see-sight-vision-blind, soul

I was studying with someone earlier today and he mentioned that he once read in the Sefer Ben Ish Hai that when a person passes away, his soul can ‘see’ (I don’t really know what that means) through this navel (belly button).

We tried looking for it later but we can’t find where it was written (he learned it a long time ago). Did anyone hear this before and can anyone provide a reference (like the parsha it was written in)?

Comment: I think it is more likely before he is born. Perhaps that is what he read somewhere.

Comment: That could be possible.

Comment: as *interested* mentioned, maybe because the baby gets his nutrients through the navel